# Prove that a limit exist for a function

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

We have $f(x)$:

$\lim_{x\to\infty} (f^2(x)) = L > 0 $

We need to prove/contradict that:

$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \sqrt{L} > 0$

I didn't find any counterexample and I'm having trouble proving it...any help?

Comment: $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational, $f(x)=-1$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a counterexample:

$$f(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$$

Comment: Can I get a more simplified example? thanks